# How can I require a model and use it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how can I require a model of my rails project and use it.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
app/
  constrollers/
    users.rb
  models/
    users.rb
```

By default I can use the `user` model in the `user` controller without having to require it. How is that possible? And, what If I want to require it in other file:

```
app/
  constrollers/
    user.rb
  models/
    user.rb
  jobs/
    cronjob.rb # I want to require models/user.rb from here and use it.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Read up on autoloading: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has some autoloading logic, documented [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Quoting from that document:

> By default, the autoload paths of an application consist of all the subdirectories of app that exist when the application boots ---except for assets, javascripts, views,--- plus the autoload paths of engines it might depend on.

Speaking to your example, you can trust not only that the contents of `models/user.rb` are available in `jobs/cronjob.rb` but also vice versa.